# Partial derivative of a fraction with a summation in the denominator

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

> Suppose I have the following function
> $$
> f(\beta_1,\beta_2,s,p)=\frac{e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}}{\sum_{s=1}^p e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}},
> $$
> which can be rewritten as
> $$
> e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}\cdot\sum_{s=1}^p e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}.
> $$
> I would like to find $\frac{\partial f(\beta_1,\beta_2,s,p)}{\partial \beta_1}$.

My approach:

$\frac{\partial e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}}{\partial \beta_1} = s \cdot e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2} $

$\frac{\sum_{s=1}^p e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}}{\partial \beta_1} = \sum_{s=1}^p -s \cdot e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}$

Yielding according to the product rule:

$\frac{\partial f(\beta_1,\beta_2,s,p)}{\partial \beta_1}=s \cdot e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}\cdot \sum_{s=1}^p e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}+e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2} \cdot \sum_{s=1}^p -s \cdot e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}$

Can anyone confirm whether or not this is correct? I look forward to your suggestions!

Another approach:

$\frac{\sum_{s=1}^p e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}}{\partial \beta_1} = \sum_{s=1}^p s \cdot e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}$

Then using the quotient rule

$\frac{\partial f(\beta_1,\beta_2,s,p)}{\partial \beta_1}=\frac{s \cdot e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2} \cdot \sum_{s=1}^p e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}+ e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}\cdot \sum_{s=1}^p s\cdot e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)} }{(\sum_{s=1}^p\cdot e^{(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)})^2}$

Comment: Are you sure that $$\left(\sum_{s=1}^p e^{\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{s=1}^p e^{-(\beta_1 s+\beta_2 s^2)}\:?$$

Comment: I'll chime in with vitamin d.  The two expressions are not the same in general.  Is the problem is posed so that the four parameters are set to make it so?

Comment: Doesn't the use of s as the index of summation make the statement ambiguous? Might need to change that for clarity.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can interchange summation and the inverse. Is this a mistake?